# How can I sync my data from an external database in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, rails-activerecord

I'm importing information from another database into my Rails database.  At the moment I've queried the database to get all records from a table and then I create new objects of my model and assign the values.  I'm wanting to detect if a record has been updated though, and if it has then I will update the record.  The records have roughly 40 attributes.  What method can I use to query the database to see if a record has changed?  Currently I'm using the following method but it seems slow.

```
SELECT A.attribute1, A.attribute2, A.attribute3, ...
  FROM external.dbo.myobject A
 INNER JOIN internal.dbo.myobject B
    ON A.key = B.key
 WHERE (A.attribute1 <> B.attribute1 OR
        A.attribute2 <> B.attribute2 OR
        A.attribute3 <> B.attribute3 OR
        ...)
```

Comment: Could you provide more info ? For example, internal rows are copied into external database, these "external" rows rows are updated (some of them) and then you have to detect only updated rows ? What happens when the same row (same ID / PK value) is updated on both sides: external and internal ? There are more "external" databases or there are plans to use two or more external databases ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean, my apologies. At the moment the internal database will not be edited, as all editing will happen with the external database that I'm importing records from.  I will just be reading from the internal database.  So the only check I can for see is seeing if the external database record has an attribute that is different than the internal database. If so, update the internal record to match the external record.   I would not need to check the reverse.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) To detect changes, simplest solution is to use [EXCEPT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx)

Above query/statement

```
INSERT INTO #changes (...)
SELECT ... FROM external.dbo.object
EXCEPT
SELECT ... FROM internal.dbo.object
```

insert into `#changes` all rows from `external.dbo.object` that are different or doesn't exist in `internal.dbo.object`.

For sync I would use [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement (see above examples):

```
MERGE   dbo.InternalObj AS i
USING   #changes AS e ON i.ID = e.ID
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE SET ... 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN INSERT ... -- This clause INSERT new rows
```

2) Another option to detect changes is to use [ROWVERSION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) data type which is a binary value **automatically** generated when rows are inserted or **updated**.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.InternalObj (
    ID      INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ColA    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    rw      BINARY(8) NOT NULL 
);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.ExternalObj (
    ID      INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    ColA    VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    rw      ROWVERSION NOT NULL -- When ColA values are changed, SQL Server will automaticcaly update [rw]
);
GO
INSERT dbo.ExternalObj (ColA) VALUES ('A')
INSERT dbo.ExternalObj (ColA) VALUES ('B')
GO

-- First test & sync
MERGE   dbo.InternalObj AS i
USING   dbo.ExternalObj AS e ON i.ID = e.ID
WHEN MATCHED AND i.rw <> e.rw -- Same [ID] but differet [rw] values
    THEN
    UPDATE -- This clause update changed rows
    SET i.ColA  = e.ColA,
        i.rw    = e.rw 
WHEN NOT MATCHED
    THEN 
    INSERT  (ID, ColA, rw) -- This clause INSERT new rows
    VALUES  (e.ID, e.ColA, e.rw);
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.InternalObj;
/*
ID          ColA rw
----------- ---- ------------------
1           A    0x0000000000000FA6
2           B    0x0000000000000FA7
*/
GO

-- Second test & sync
INSERT dbo.ExternalObj (ColA) VALUES ('C')
UPDATE  dbo.ExternalObj
SET     ColA = ColA + '#'
WHERE   ID = 2
GO
MERGE   dbo.InternalObj AS i
USING   dbo.ExternalObj AS e ON i.ID = e.ID
WHEN MATCHED AND i.rw <> e.rw -- Same [ID] but differet [rw] values
    THEN
    UPDATE -- This clause update changed rows
    SET i.ColA  = e.ColA,
        i.rw    = e.rw 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT  (ID, ColA, rw) -- This clause INSERT new rows
    VALUES  (e.ID, e.ColA, e.rw);
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.InternalObj;
/*
ID          ColA rw
----------- ---- ------------------
1           A    0x0000000000000FA6
2           B#   0x0000000000000FA9
3           C    0x0000000000000FA8
*/
GO
```

I would use [ROWVERSION] if I need to detect changes in **any** column.

Note: a simple like `UPDATE ... SET ColA = <the same value>` will change [rw] value for affected rows.

3) Third solution uses [BINARY_CHECKSUM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx) function to generate checksum values for every row. By comparing these checksum values for every ID / row we can detect changes

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.InternalObj DROP COLUMN [rw]
ALTER TABLE dbo.ExternalObj DROP COLUMN [rw]
GO

-- Test / sync
;WITH CteTarget
AS (
    SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS CRC
    FROM (
    SELECT  ID, ColA -- Only selected columns
    FROM    dbo.InternalObj 
    ) x
), CteSource
AS (
    SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(*) AS CRC
    FROM (
    SELECT  ID, ColA -- Only selected columns
    FROM    dbo.ExternalObj 
    ) y
)
MERGE   CteTarget i
USING   CteSource e ON i.ID = e.ID 
WHEN MATCHED AND EXISTS(SELECT i.CRC EXCEPT SELECT e.CRC) -- Same [ID] but differet [CRC] values 
    THEN
    UPDATE -- This clause update changed rows
    SET i.ColA  = e.ColA
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
    THEN 
    INSERT  (ID, ColA) -- This clause INSERT new rows
    VALUES  (e.ID, e.ColA);
GO
SELECT * FROM dbo.InternalObj;
/*
ID          ColA
----------- ----
1           A
2           B
*/
GO
```

Note: `BINARY_CHECKSUM` function could generate hash collisions (rows with different values => same checksum => changes are not detected).